# dataframe use udf have problem caused by partition

Tags: pyspark

I know that the dataframe in pyspark has their partition and when I apply a function (udf) on one column, different partition will apply the same function in parallel.

```py
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, 1, 'A', '2017-01-01'),
        (2, 3, 'B', '2017-01-02'),
        (3, 5, 'A', '2017-01-03'),
        (4, 7, 'B', '2017-01-04')
    ],
    ('index', 'X', 'label', 'date')
)
```

```py
data=df.rdd.map(lambda x:x['label']).collect()
```

```py
def ad(x):
    return data.pop(0).lower()
AD=F.udf(ad,StringType())
```

```py
df.withColumn('station',AD('label')).select('station').rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()
```

here is the output:

```py
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

which should be:

```py
['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

And the most strange thing is that

```py
data
```

didn't even change after we call the functio

```py
data.pop(0)
```

Comment: This question sounds interessting. Could you please add a [minimal reproducible example[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples).

Comment: Hey there, I just add a sample data you can play with.

Comment: I get the expected output: `['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']` with Spark 2.4 and Python3. `data` also changes after callin `data.pop(0)`. Could you please check your question again?

Comment: @cronoik  try increase the number of partition. and then you will get the same result as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It turns out when the number of partition increases, the function will apply on each partition with the same

```py
data
```

which means, the data is deepcopyed and will not be change.

Every time we use F.udf, it will deepcopy every variable inside the function.